# R - "Browser()" on Error?

Tags: r

I have been using some R libraries to analyze some large data recently, and I find myself frustrated by waiting several hours for the beginning of an analysis, just to get to the end and receive some trivial error, like that I did not install a prerequisite library, or that one of my parameters was wrong.  So, then I have to start all over, do the exact same analysis, generate the same variables that it had when it died, and wait a long time.  Please note that these are not handled exceptions--they are fatal errors from R.

This is just a thought--and perhaps it is too good to be true, so please at least explain why it wouldn't work--but is there any way to cause R to execute "browser()" in the environment whenever it has a fatal error?  For example, say it is executing a script, and encounters "require(notInstalledYet)".  Instead of just dying, and losing all the variables in the memory, it would be great if it would give me a browser() at the place it died, so that I could at least save the variables, and at best, fix the problem (e.g. install the library) and try again.

Comment: You could write some kind of customer error handler (see [R Language Definition#Exception handling#Error options](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Error-options)), but I'm not sure if you can set it up to do that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change the error option to open a browser on error

```
options(error=browser)
```

the default is

```
options(error=NULL)
```

Comment: ...that's perfect.  I am a little embarrassed I didn't find it on my own, but I thought it seemed too good to be true that a simple one liner would enable this function.  Thanks so much!